# Can't set ReactiveDict-var in onRendered-function

Tags: javascript, meteor

Why does this give me a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`?

```
Template.something.onCreated(function() {
    this.templateDictionary = new ReactiveDict();
});

Template.something.onRendered(function() {
    Template.templateDictionary.set( 'showExtraFields', true );
});

Template.something.helpers({
    anything: function() {
        var result = Template.instance().templateDictionary.get( 'showExtraFields' );
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onRendered` function needs to be fixed:

```
Template.something.onRendered(function() {
    Template.instance().templateDictionary.set( 'showExtraFields', true );
});
```